# something wrong with PHP file preventing JSON data from parsing

Tags: android

I developed search function when I type a value in the search bar a toast shows unable to parse, but there is nothing wrong with the android side, the problem lies in the PHP script.

For example when I type "Art" this is the response from the server that doesn't show on the app only in the log:

```
s = {"result":[{"post_id":"390","post_title":"Cart","post_date":"2017-02-07 12:17:29"},{"post_id":"421","post_title":"Front End Developer - Digital Arts","post_date":"2017-02-07 12:18:04"},{"post_id":"431","post_title":"Art Director","post_date":"2017-02-07 12:18:19"}]}
```

This is my parser class:

```
public class Parser extends AsyncTask <Void, Void,Integer> {

    Context ctx;
    ListView listView;
    String data;
    ArrayList<Skill> skills = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayAdapter adapter;
    ArrayList<String> titles = new ArrayList<>();

        public Parser(Context ctx, String data, ListView listView) {
            this.ctx = ctx;
            this.data=data;
            this.listView = listView;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {
            return this.parse();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Integer integer) {
            super.onPostExecute(integer);
            if (integer == 1) {
                adapter = new ArrayAdapter(ctx, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, titles);
    //          CustomAdapter mAdapter = new CustomAdapter(ctx,skills);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        Intent toSkillActivity = new Intent(ctx,SkillActivity.class);
                        toSkillActivity.putExtra("skill",skills.get(position));
                        ctx.startActivity(toSkillActivity);
                    }});
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(ctx, "Unable to Parse", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }


        private int parse() {
            try {
                Log.d("Jou","data");
                JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(data);
                JSONObject jo = null;
                titles.clear();
                skills.clear();
                for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {
                    jo = ja.getJSONObject(i);
                    String author = jo.getString("post_author");
                    String title = jo.getString("post_title");
                    //String content = jo.getString("post_content");/* authoer is better :P */
                    String date = jo.getString("post_date");
                    Skill skill = new Skill();
                    skill.setAuthor(author);
                    skill.setTitle(title);
                    //skill.setContent(content);
                    skill.setDate(date);
                    skills.add(skill);
                    titles.add(title);
                }
                return 1;
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.d("Jou", e.getMessage());
                return 0;
            }
        }}
```

And here is PHP script:

```
<?php
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = '';
$dbpass = '';
$conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die ("Unable to connect") ;
if(! $conn )
{
 echo 'Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error();
}
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
mysqli_set_charset($conn, 'utf8');

$search ="";
if(isset($_REQUEST['query'] )){
   $search = $_REQUEST['query'];
}
if($search != ""){

   $sql = "SELECT post_author,post_title,post_date FROM `wp_posts` WHERE post_title LIKE '%".$search."%'";

    mysqli_select_db($conn,'');

$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql ) or die ("Error: ".mysqli_error($conn));;
$result = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){

array_push($result,
    array('post_author'=>$row['post_author'],
        'post_title'=>$row['post_title'],
        'post_date'=>$row['post_date']
    ));
}
    echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result));
}else{
   echo 'No search field has been sent';
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `data` variable is `JSONObject` you must get `JSONArray` from `data` like this :

```
JSONArray ja = data.getJSONArray("result")
```